# openGL - I want the camera to get closer to the object, how?

Tags: qt, opengl, graphics, 3d, camera

I used the Qt equivalent to the gluLookAt to set my view matrix and I've been moving it by translating it everywhere in the scene.. now I want to get close with the camera to an object.

I know the position of the object, both in object coords and in each other coords (I have the model matrix for that object), but how to get the position of the camera?

To animate the camera to get closer and closer to the object I suppose I should take two points:

- The point where the object is
- The point where the camera is

and then do something like

```
QVector3D direction_to_get_closer = point_where_object_is - point_where_camera_is
```

How do I get the point where the camera is? Or, alternatively if this is not needed, how do I get the vector to the direction the camera has to follow (no rotations, I just need translations, this is going to simplify things) to reach the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gluLookAt(eye, target, headUp) takes three parameters, the position of the camera/eye, the position of the object you want to look at, and a unitvector to controll roll/head up direction.

To zoom closer, you can move the eye/camera position by some fraction of your vector direction_to_get_closer. For instance,

```
point_where_camera_is += 0.1f * direction_to_get_closer; // move 10% closer
```

Its more useful to move by a constant amount instead of 10% of the current distance (or else you will move very fast when the distance is great, and then increasingly slower). Therefore, you should use the normalized direction:

```
 QVector3D unitDir = direction_to_get_closer.normalized();
 point_where_camera_is += 0.1f * unitDir; // move 0.1 units in direction
```

The camera transform will break if point_where_camera_is becomes equal to point_where_object_is.

A better way, if you don't need to zoom, translate/rotate the new "zoomed" point_where_camera_is is to interpolate between to positions.

```
float t = some user input value between 0 and 1 (0% to 100% of the line camToObj)
QVector3D point_on_line_cam_obj = t * point_where_camera_is + (1-t) * point_where_object_is;
```

This way, you can stop the user from zooming into the object by limiting t, also, you can go back to the start position with t=0;